# Using Auto Increment and Not Null

Tags: mysql

Is there any point in following up a AUTO INCREMENT with a NOT NULL?
Seeing as the db takes care of this, I assumed a AUTO INCREMENT will always have a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because it is possible to manually insert data into this field. You wouldn't want anyone intentionally or accidentally adding a record that placed a NULL in your identity field.

On the flip side, if you are not using the field as an artificial key but for some other purpose, and having a null value is ok, then sure leave it off.

Comment: Although, if you leave it off (or try to make it explicitly nullable), it's silently coerced back in if the auto-increment is part of the primary key:  *"Columns that are part of a `PRIMARY KEY` are made `NOT NULL` even if not declared that way."* -- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/silent-column-changes.html

Comment: Great point. Just keep in mind that auto increment fields are not just for PKs. I have had occasion to use them in non-PKs as well.